# I want to build my own terminal, but when I move right in the terminal it prints ^[[D instead of moving right

Tags: python, linux, terminal

```
import os

while True:

    os.system(input("#  "))
```

Here example:

ls `^[[D`

How can i make this to move right?

Comment: you can't create a terminal like that because when you call `input` it's a python process that is taking in text, and the left arrow key has a value of `^[[D`